# Low poly hair when exporting particles from blender to UE5

Tags: particles, hair, unreal-engine

I did my hair according to this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5XjRxbwI7A&ab_channel=pinkpocketTV
In a blender, the hair looks smooth, but in Unreal it is low-poly and not smoothed. What could be the problem?[image]